# How to tag services in Symfony 3.3 and construct a mini container from it?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, tags

I am writing a component in which multiple services have to be injected. However only a few services are required to process a request. As the services are heavy to instantiate. I would like them to be lazy instantiated.
Is it some how possible to build a mini container using only the services that have the appropriate tags?

Right now I simply inject the entire service container but from what I understand this should not be done.

Comment: I have not messed around with this but starting with S3.3, Symfony has a ServiceSubscriberInterface that the new AbstractController class uses.  I don't know the details but you might dig into the new autowire functionality to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Symfony 3.3, if you enable `autoconfigure`, then some tags are automatically applied for you like `twig.extension`.

Enable `autoconfigure` does not work for all tags. Many tags have required attributes, like event listeners, where you also need to specify the event name and method in your tag. `Autoconfigure` works only for tags without any required tag attributes